# Syntax error near "user" PostgreSQL, even though user is quoted

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error

Getting this on postgres:

```
syntax error at or near ""user""
```

For the following:

```
insert into "user" ("id", "email") values ('1', 'foo@example.com') on conflict do update "user" set "id" = '1', "email" = 'foo@example.com'
```

Been playing with it for a while, not sure where the syntax error is. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Lexib0y No, it shouldn’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you can't specify the table name in the `ON CONFLICT UPDATE SET` clause. The following seems to work:

```
insert into "user" ("id", "email") values ('1', 'foo@example.com')
on conflict do update set "id" = '1', "email" = 'foo@example.com'
```

The [syntax here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html):

```
....
DO UPDATE SET { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT } |
                ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) |
                ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( sub-SELECT )
              } [, ...]
          [ WHERE condition ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `"user"` after `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`.